# How to use React hooks with similar variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am fairly new to React hooks, and I am trying to use similar variables over again.

I want to have several buttons, each of which launch a different login mechanism, like so:

```
export default function App() {

    let [request, response, onGoogleLoginButtonPress] = Google.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: 'NUMBER',
    });
    let [request, response, onFBLoginButtonPress] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: 'NUMBER',
    });

return(

            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.googleRed, styles.loginButton]}
                  self={this} onPress={() => onGoogleLoginButtonPress()}>
                  <View></View>
                  <Text style={styles.loginText}>Log In with Google</Text>
                  <Image style={styles.loginImg} source={GoogleImg} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.facebookBlue, styles.loginButton]}
                  self={this} onPress={() => onFBLoginButtonPress()}>
                  <View></View>
                  <Text style={styles.loginText}>Log In with Facebook</Text>
                  <Image style={styles.loginImg} source={FBImg} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
);
}
```

This doesn't work, because request and response are being re-used.

Now I suppose I could re-name them fbRequest and googleRequest, etc, but that just seems messy and like adding unnecessary variables - if there's a request, it will only be ONE request.

How do I re-use these variables whilst still populating them with the relevant function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options. I prefer the first..

First, refactor your buttons into common button functional component, so you can keep them looking similar and maintainable

```
const AuthButton = (props) => {

  return(
    <TouchableOpacity style={props.styles}
      self={this} onPress={props.onPress}>
      <View></View>
      <Text style={styles.loginText}>{props.buttonText}</Text>
      <Image style={styles.loginImg} source={props.imgSrc} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )

}
```

you have two options after this.

**Option 1:** functional component for each Auth type wrapping the button with its custom hook

```
  const FacebookAuthBtn = (props) => {

    let [request, response, onButtonPress] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: '195616021512894',
    });
    
    return(
      <AuthButton 
        styles={[styles.facebookBlue, styles.loginButton]}
        imgSrc={FBImg}
        onPress={onButtonPress}
        buttonText={"Log In with Facebook"}        
      />
    )
  }
```

and then do a similar option for google.

```
  const GoogleAuthBtn = (props) => {

    let [request, response, onButtonPress] = Google.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: '195616021512894',
    });
    
    return(
      <AuthButton 
        styles={[styles.googleRed, styles.loginButton]}
        imgSrc={GoogleImg}
        onPress={onButtonPress}
        buttonText={"Log In with Google"}        
      />
    )
  }
```

and you would end up with

```
export default function App() {  


  const handleAuthenticate = (data) => {
    // do what you need to when user authenticates
  }

  return(
    <View>
      <FacebookAuthBtn onAuthenticate={handleAuthenticate} />
      <GoogleAuthBtn onAuthenticate={handleAuthenticate}/>  
    </View>  
  );
}
```

What is nice about this, is your can pass an "onAuthenticate" callback to both those components from your app level and deal with it appropriately.

you can do this in each of the FacebookAuthBtn and GoogleAuthBtn by having a useEffect on the response

```
 const FacebookAuthBtn = (props) => {

    let [request, response, onButtonPress] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: '195616021512894',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
      if (response && typeof props.onAuthenticate === 'function') {
        props.onAuthenticate(response);
      }
    },[response])
    
    return(
      <AuthButton 
        styles={[styles.facebookBlue, styles.loginButton]}
        imgSrc={FBImg}
        onPress={onButtonPress}
        buttonText={"Log In with Facebook"}        
      />
    )
  }
```

**Option 2:** use AuthButton twice (you would need to pass in the props like option 1)

```
export default function App() {

    let [gRequest, gResponse, onGoogleLoginButtonPress] = Google.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: '195616021512894',
    });
    
    let [fRequest, fResponse, onFBLoginButtonPress] = Facebook.useAuthRequest({
      responseType: ResponseType.Token,
      clientId: '195616021512894',
    });

    return(
      <View>
        <AuthButton {googleAuthPropsHere}/>  
        <AuthButton {facebookAuthPropsHere}/>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Good point, I can refactor this into a more re-usable design and solve the problem at the same time.

Comment: yup, that is the idea :)

Answer (score 1):

I see your point, but they aren't unnecessary. Each is related to the specific `useAuthRequest` call that you're making. You can't share them across two of those calls.

You could in a `class` component, because they handle state slightly differently, but not with a hook like `useAuthRequest`.